# ElasticSearch sliced scroll limit (python)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scroll, size

I'm working with a huge (5 million documents) ElasticSearch database and I need to fetch data using sliced scroll in python. Question is: if there is some way to limit (set `size` param) the sliced scroll? I tried to set `size` param by `[search obj].param(size=500000)` or `[:500000]` but it doesn't seem to work - sliced scroll gives me all documents.

In my script, I'm using sliced scroll with python multiprocessing like in here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/817

Is there some way to get for example 500000 documents using sliced scroll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Elasticsearch scan-and-scroll, is there a way to control both the batch size and limit the number of documents in the search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707316/in-elasticsearch-scan-and-scroll-is-there-a-way-to-control-both-the-batch-size)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from github:

"There is no limit on scroll, it always returns all documents. To only get a subset simply stop consuming the iterator after you get the number you wanted to retrieve by using a break statement or similar."

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/817